# If $p(x)\leq f(x)\leq q(x)$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}q(x)=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Is the above correct? More specifically, is $\lim_{x\to \infty}2^{\sin x}x=\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

The [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) is correct and we can use it observing that

$$\frac12 \le2^{\sin x} \le 2$$

and therefore

$$2^{\sin x}x \ge \frac12x$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct because it is a three function Theorem.